# non-unifrom distribution for generated lines

Tags: javascript, random, trigonometry

For a demo of the problem I am having, see this <s>[fiddle][removed]</s>.

Basically, I am generating a line that touches the wall of a square `#block`. The problem is that the lines do not seem to be distributed as I'd expect (after enough lines are added). Here is the output that I expect:

[image: Expected output]
**And here is the output that I get**:

[image: Actual output]

You can recreate this by hitting the <kbd>add 100</kbd> button. I can't seem to figure out why there is a high concentration of lines at the bottom, where the maximum length of the line is, but such a low concentration near the minimum length. Here is, specifically, how I generate the length of the line, where the min is **half the width of the square**, and the max is the **distance from the center to a corner** (calculated with Pythagorean's theorem):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

The crux of the issue is that I want to get output like I expect, with lines that completely fill this 45 degree section rather than crowd around the bottom.

### Full code:

#### HTML

```
<div id="block"></div>
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="add100">add 100</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<label id="count">0 lines</label>
```

---

#### CSS

```
#block {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.line {
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    background-color:black;
}
```

---

#### JS

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    //generate a div with a random id
    var lineId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 32768);
    $('#block').append('<div class="line" id="line' + lineId + '"></div>');
    var curLine = $('#line' + lineId);

    $('#count').html($('#block > div').size() + " lines");

    //get properties of the block
    var xmax = parseInt($('#block').css("height"), 10); //200
    var ymax = parseInt($('#block').css("width"), 10); //200

    //(xcen, ycen) is the origin of the points
    var xcen = xmax / 2;
    var ycen = ymax / 2;
    curLine.css("left", (xcen + 9) + "px"); //9 is horizontal offset
    curLine.css("top", (ycen + 8) + "px"); //8 is vertical offset

    //the longest line would go from the origin to the corner: the hypotenuse
    var maxlen = Math.sqrt((xcen * xcen) + (ycen * ycen));

    //the shortest line would go from the origin straight up: the shortest leg
    var minlen = (xcen <= ycen) ? xcen : ycen;

    //the length of the line will be between the shortest length, and longest
    var height = getRandomInt(minlen, maxlen);
    curLine.css("height", height + "px");

    // arcsin (opposite/hypotenuse) converted to degrees
    var angle = Math.asin(xcen / height) * (180 / Math.PI);
    curLine.css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
    curLine.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

$('#add100').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    $('#add').trigger('click');
});

$('#clear').click(function () {
    $('.line').remove();
    $('#count').html($('#block > div').size() + " lines");
});
```

---

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I don't see an explicit question.

Comment: Sorry, it was kind of difficult to phrase. I tried to sum it up right before where I posted the code, but essentially, "What math am I misunderstanding here with how these line lengths are calculated?" "Why do gaps seem to form in the same spots, despite using random lengths?" I expect the lengths/angles to perfectly create a filled triangle, instead there are large gaps between certain areas.

Comment: @TimothyShields Hopefully I was able to explain what I meant with this... please feel free to edit/comment if you know a better way to phrase what I am after. I am afraid the title is particularly weak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of these possible line segments' lengths is skewed towards longer lines. If you uniformly sample a length between 1 and sqrt(2), you're going to have more lines near the bottom of your triangle than near the top.

Randomly generate the left endpoint: generate lines from (0,R) to (1,1) where R is a uniform random variable in the range [0,1].

The reason this "makes sense" is as follows.  Suppose I draw 11 segments in this way, whose left endpoints are (0,0),(0,0.1),(0,0.2),...,(0,0.9),(0,1) and whose right endpoints are all (1,1). Then the area of the triangles between consecutive triangles will all be equal: WIDTH*HEIGHT/2 = 0.1*1/2 = 0.05.

When randomly sampling the left endpoint as (0,R), where R is uniform in the range [0,1], you are effectively getting the same behavior as was described in the previous paragraph. If you were to go through the same reasoning but with your original method (uniformly sampling line lengths), you would find that the area of triangle "gaps" between lines are *not* uniformly distributed: namely, the gaps are bigger near the top than near the bottom.

If this is what you want, great. If not, why not?